# jquery ui-tabs widget , changing the color of the background with css causes problem with display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the jquery tabs plugin and want to have the background a light grey color.  In the css section for tabs, I found this line of code where I manually added the background-color part:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em 1em; display: block; border-width: 0; background-color:#EEEEEE;}
```

The problem comes as seen in the picture below, where the grey background is only extending down part of the way.  I initially thought I could update the div container with the same background color, but it didn't work.  It looks like that white portion below might be some kind of padding, so I looked for that in the css but everything I tried had the same effect.

Anyone got some ideas?

[alt text http://www.redsandstech.com/ui_tab.jpg](http://www.redsandstech.com/ui_tab.jpg)

This is what the HTML looks like (Theoretically):

```
<div id="tabs_here">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="$('#T_1').html('Display the data');" >Item Groups</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div id="T_1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple, but sometimes it's the simple solutions you miss... check if `#T_1` or`#tabs_here` have a specific height specified, or add `overflow:hidden` to them to check, it looks like your content is extending past them.

Comment: Well, it didn't end up being a sizing problem with the div, but I found the problem in this line of the css: .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #a6c9e2; background: #fcfdfd url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png) 50% bottom repeat-x; color: #222222; }

If I remove the background part it works...but I'm afraid if I remove this I will cause other problems with some jquery widgets that might use this later on...is this true?

Comment: you can set the background-position on just that widget, i.e.
`#T_1{ background-position: 0 0; }`, or if you have this problem on multiple tabs `#tabs_here .ui-tabs-panel{ background-position: 0 0; }`